# Every quotient is a colimit and every subspace is a limit

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I have been wondering for a while about the following question:

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $f \colon X \to S$ is surjective. Define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x ∼ x' \Longleftrightarrow f(x )= f(x')$.

Let $R = \{(x, x') ∈ X × X \mid f(x) = f(x')\}$

There are two maps, call them $r_1 \colon R → X$ and $r_2 \colon R → X$, defined by the composition of inclusion $R → X × X$ with the two natural projections $\pi_1,\pi_2\colon X × X → X$, i.e. $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the compositions $R→X × X\rightrightarrows X$ where the last two arrows are $(π_1,π_2)$.

Learn what a coequalizer is and prove that the set $S$ with the quotient topology (coming from $X/\!\!\sim$) is the coequalizer of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Here is another related question:

Similarly here, I need to show that every subspace is a limit using also the previous result.

Let $f \colon Y → X$ be an embedding of a space $Y$ into a space $X$. Construct a diagram for which $Y$
(and the map $f$) is a limit. I was given a hint here that I can use the previous result that shows that quotients are coequalizers and hence colimits.

This clarifies why subspaces and products have similar categorical properties (since they are both limits) and why quotients and coproducs have similar categorical properties (since they are both colimits).

Comment: It does not make sense to ask if a morphism is a limit. Similarly, the statement that subspaces are limits does not make any sense. There is a way to make these statements correct, though. Please clarify the question. Also, it is not good to post the actual problem inside of an image (no full text search, and bad for a11y), so please take the time and write down the actual problem. PS: I have removed the wrong tags "algebraic topology" and "topological groups". Please choose only tags where you know that they fit to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and clarifications. I appreciate your guidance on the precision of statements regarding morphisms and subspaces as limits. Could you please elaborate on how making them correct and prove them! I'll ensure to provide a clearer and more accurate formulation of the question now. I'll also take into consideration your suggestion about posting the actual problem in text for better accessibility and searchability. Your removal of the incorrect tags is duly noted, and I'll be more mindful in selecting appropriate tags going forward. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: It should be mentioned that these are exercises 1.12 and 4.1 in _Topology, A Categorical Approach_ by Bradley, Bryson, Terilla.